# Game UI without using libraries

Tags: java, lwjgl

I want to make my own simple game UI, and I think I know how the main stuff is done. The thing is that I don't know how to draw simple 2D quads by using screen coordinates in a 3D view? Is that even possible? Maybe I should draw game UI in another way?

Please don't recommend any libraries. I would like to learn how it is done, not use something existing.

Comment: As a games industry veteran of 10 years, I can say the way it is done is you use an existing library. Unless your plan is to create a UI interface library.

Comment: why would i use a library for five simple buttons?

Comment: Well i think the most dificult thing is what i asked here. And the other stuff is simple: draw a quad, if (mouse coordinates are in the quad) { if(mousedown) { do something }}

Comment: @user714965 oh, and why are you askig this?

Comment: if you set your model and view matrices to identity matrices, vertex coords in the range of [-1,1] will correspond to the screen width/height, so (-1,-1) would be top-left and (1,1) bottom-right

Comment: @Torious you could write a full anwser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you included the lwjgl tag, this is how it is typically done in OpenGL in general, which should work fine for you, too:

1. Render your underlying game scene as usual
2. Setup the view so that you have an orthographic view that you can render on top of the scene. It will have units that range from -1.0f,-1.0f (left,top of screen) to 1.0f,1.0f (bottom, right of screen) and will draw over the top of your already-rendered game scene underneath.

   ```
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   ```
3. Render textured quads with coordinates from -1.0f to 1.0f

   ```
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   // <== Bind your texture, material for your GUI button here
   glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0);
   glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
   glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0);
   glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
   glEnd();
   ```

This gives you resolution independence. So if you play the game at 800x600, the quad will be one size, but if you then play at 1024x768, it will automatically grow to fill the same proportional area of the screen.

If you really want to write directly in screen coordinates, then you can setup your glOrtho that way instead (range from 0.0 to 800.0 for example). But that's not recommended.

Comment: the quad is drawn but there is no 3D view behind it

Comment: Assuming he does step #1, then that will be visible "behind" it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the projection to orthogonal using 
GLU.gluOrtho2D(0f, glutScreenWidth, 0f, glutScreenHeight);

This is how JBullet sets up the projection for text drawing (they use 1 as the z coordinate in FontRenderer):

```
// See http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glut/index.php?bmpfontortho
public void setOrthographicProjection() {
  // switch to projection mode
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

  // save previous matrix which contains the 
  // settings for the perspective projection
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  // reset matrix
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  // set a 2D orthographic projection
  gl.gluOrtho2D(0f, glutScreenWidth, 0f, glutScreenHeight);
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  gl.glLoadIdentity();

  // invert the y axis, down is positive
  gl.glScalef(1f, -1f, 1f);
  // mover the origin from the bottom left corner
  // to the upper left corner
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, -glutScreenHeight, 0f);
}
```

See https://github.com/affogato/JBullet-QIntBio-Fork/blob/master/src/com/bulletphysics/demos/opengl/ and look at the FontRenderer and  LwjglGL classes...